# index and section issue in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, list, uitableview, indexing

i got a tableview controller. in the table view i have huge list of scrambled names. sectioning works well, it groups all the names according to the first letter of the name however the table view lists the names in the order of the written code in Xcode. here is the piece of code i use:

```
SongsIndexTitles = @[@"A", @"B", @"C",@"Ç", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I",@"İ", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"Ö", @"P", @"R", @"S",@"Ş", @"T", @"U",@"Ü", @"V", @"Y", @"Z"];


allTableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Aglarsa Anam Ağlar" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Aynalı Kemer" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Boşuna " andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Çöpçüler " andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Ahu Gozlum" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Hepsi Senin mi?" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Adin Ne" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Pamuk" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin"],
                [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Sen Yoluna Ben Yoluma" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin "],
                [[Songs alloc] initWithName:@"Yolcu Yolunda Gerek" andDescription:@"Seslendiren: Abidin "],
```

...

it goes on and on. what i need to do is to list "Adin Ne" prior to "Aglarsa Anam Aglar" automatically. like i said sectioning works perfect, but listing is no good.

would appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Sort your "Songs" array after adding data to it.

NSArray *sortedArray = [Songs sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

Comment: NSPredicates or sorting descriptors much?

Comment: @SamraanKhaan it gives me the error: No known class method for selector 'sortedArrayUsingSelector'

Comment: NSArray *sortedArray = [allTableData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

Try this.

Comment: this was the first thing i tried, it gives a warning : unused variable 'sortedArray' and when i run the sim, it crushes the app. one more thing, where am i suppose to put this piece of code?

Comment: by the way Songs is an NSObject which is imported from the Songs.h file...

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just sort allTableData using `sortedArrayUsingComparator` of NSArray.

Sort it using `[string1 compare:string2 options:NSNumericSearch];` inside block of `sortedArrayUsingComparator`

Then use it as Datasource of Table.